# Ruby On Rails: Error Message When Trying To Start WEBrick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webrick

I'm a TOTAL NEWBIE trying to learn Rails from a Lynda.com Ruby on Rails tutorial. I've got Rails 3.0 installed and Ruby Germs 1.8. Up to this point in the tutorial, I have created a Rails project and we are just about to access it. The tutor says that I should be able to type

```
rails server
```

in the terminal on a mac to boot up WEBrick which comes installed with Rails.

However, when I do it, I got the error message below (which I can't make sense of).   **Do you know what I can do to get WEBrick working?

Note: I have mysql installed locally (/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql) and it is running. I also have MAMP installed but it is not running (I only use it for PHP applications). I would also like to use mysql and WEBrick so that I can work along with the tutorial, but if there's an alternative solution that you can think of please also let me know...

```
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.3.2/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle: dlopen(/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.3.2/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib (LoadError)
  Referenced from: /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.3.2/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
  Reason: image not found - /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.3.2/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.3.2/lib/mysql2.rb:8
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.14/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.14/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.14/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.14/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.14/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.14/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.14/lib/bundler.rb:120:in `require'
    from /Users/michaelmitchell/Sites/simple_cms/config/application.rb:7
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:28:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:28
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:27:in `tap'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:27
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6
```

UPDATE  I tried a reinstall of mysql2 like this

```
sudo gem install mysql2 — –with-mysql-configs=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config
```

error message

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed mysql2-0.3.6
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem '—' (>= 0) in any repository
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem '–with-mysql-configs=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config' (>= 0) in any repository
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for mysql2-0.3.6...

Enclosing class/module 'mMysql2' for class Client not known

Enclosing class/module 'mMysql2' for class Result not known
Installing RDoc documentation for mysql2-0.3.6...

Enclosing class/module 'mMysql2' for class Client not known

Enclosing class/module 'mMysql2' for class Result not known
```

Comment: The error message complains about a mysql dynamic library. Do you have mysql installed locally, because the `mysql2` gem won't work without it, iirc.

Comment: Do you have mysql installed on your system? Did you run `bundle` before `rails server`?

Comment: I have mysql installed locally and it is running. Am I supposed to run bundle? The tutorial didn't do that.... Should I?

Comment: Note, I also have MAMP installed on my computer but it is not running. There is a locally installed mysql running

Comment: Bundle installs all the necessary gems. You could also remove `mysql2` from your Gemfile and go with `sqlite3`, which is less of hassle to set up.

Comment: do I just do "bundle" by itself?  I'd prefer to stick with the tutorial and try mysql

Comment: I did bundle and I got. "Your bundle is complete! Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed." but when I did rails server again, I got the same problem

Comment: Note, I also have MAMP installed but it's not running so I'm assuming it's not causing a conflict...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and the comments above doesn't relate to your mistake. What the video didn't make you do was **cd** back to **simple_cms**. You were trying to execute the rails server command in the Sites folder (thats where the video leaves you) which is impossible. Make sure you **cd back** to **simple_cms** and do **rails server.**

Answer (score 0):

try this out:

```
cd /Applications/MAMP/Library/lib/mysql/
ln -s  ibmysqlclient.la ibmysqlclient.a
ln -s libmysqlclient_r.la libmysqlclient_r.a
ln -s libndbclient.la libndbclient.a

sudo gem install mysql2 — –with-mysql-configs=/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql_config
```

Comment: can you tell me what it's going to do and what I will need to do after?  Will I need to run MAMP after to get it working instead of the local mysql at /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql?

Comment: your **mysql2** has been installed incorrectly, only thing you need is reinstall it again with properly config pointed to MAMP MySQL config **=/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql_config**. You only need to be sure that mysqld is running

Comment: but why do I need to point it to MAMP? I'm not using MAMP (MAMP's only being used for php applications).  I have mysql installed here /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql for Rails...

Comment: ok, just reinstall the **mysql2** gem with sudo gem install mysql2 — –with-mysql-configs=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config.

Comment: I did the reinstall as you describe. If you look in the OP "Update" it gave me an error message. Problem?  Note, I also tried to launch with "rails server" again and got the same error message...

Comment: As for your last update, it should be: `sudo gem install mysql2 —–with-mysql-configs=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config` instead of `sudo gem install mysql2 — –with-mysql-configs=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config` (There shouldn't be a space between the two dashes in front of `with-mysql-configs=`).